# Please explain how the parameter y is geting increased once the if statment is met

Tags: javascript

I dont understand why once the condition is met and it returns [y-1] the y in parameter in the range function goes up by 1 until it reaches 9,should it not s go down until it reaches 0 based on the else condition or something like that?

```js
function range(x, y) {

  if (y - x == 2) {

    return [y - 1];

  } else {

    var up = range(x, y - 1);

  }
}
console.log(range(2, 9));
```

Comment: It seems you don't have a return statement in the else condition, so the function just returns nothing if an else condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing has to do with the way your function is structured. For instance, what is the use of the variable `up`? All you do is assign a value, but never use it. Your intent is clear and can be stated as pseudo-code like this:

- Accept two integers with the the second being at least two higher
  than the first
- If the second minus the first is equal to 2 then
  return the second value minus one
- Otherwise, subtract one from the second value and do the operation again

Here is a quick implementation of that code. Please note there is ALWAYS a return to ensure output the terminal value:

```js
function range(x, y) {
  return (y - x == 2) ? y - 1 : range(x, y - 1);
}
console.log(range(2, 9));
```

If you are not familiar with ternary operators, this is how they work:

( TEST ) ? Do this if TEST return true : otherwise do this

Comment: Thank you for the advice should have enterd the whole code to make it clearer but was olnly interested in that section of the code,here is the whole code:                 
  var range = function(x, y) 
{
  if (y - x === 2) 
  {
    return [x + 1];
  } 
  else 
  {
    var up = range(x, y - 1);
    up.push(y - 1);
    return up;
  }
};

console.log(range(2,9));

Comment: I ran the code in debugging just to see how the values are passed and the thing that i din't really get is why once the if statement returned [y+1] the y parameter in the function grows from 4 to 5,i thought it should go down stil because of the recursion of the range(x, y-1) function